# Probability of dealing pairs Texas Holdem

Tags: probability

I am in my first statistics/probability class and I am having trouble with this problem.

In two player Texas hold'em, what is the probaility that neither player is dealt a pair? What is the probability when you have three players?

I know you can solve it inelegantly by breaking it into a bunch of cases, but is there an easy general way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you can calculate the chance that the first player does not get a pair, which we can call $p$.  An approximate approach is to say the chance the second player does not get a pair is independent of the first, so the chance neither player gets a pair is $p^2$ and for three players it is $p^3$.  This is not exact.  The fact that the first player did not get a pair has left a deck with $2$ ranks that have only $3$ copies and $11$ ranks that still have $4$.  The right way is to condition on whether the first card drawn by the second player comes from a rank that has $3$ or $4$ cards at the start of his draw.  This is not too bad.  When you get to three players, it is a mess. Assuming the second player does not get a pair, there are three different deck compositions possible for the third player to draw from.  Each one will give the third player a slightly different probability of getting a pair.